# How can I clear the uCommerce dataprovider cache?

Tags: data-provider, ucommerce

I'm importing products into a Sitecore uCommerce site and referencing these new products using the uCommerce Sitecore data provider.

The products are successfully imported and show in the uCommerce interface but they don't immediately show in the products bucket (Sitecore/uCommerce/Products).

I've tried:

```
 - ObjectFactory.Instance.Resolve<ICacheProvider>().ClearCache();
 - ObjectFactory.Instance.Resolve<ScratchIndexer>().Index();
 - Clearing all the sitecore caches (cache.aspx)
```

but none of these work.

As soon as I recycle the app pool they appear as expected.

Is there something else I need to call from my import code to make the data provider work without a recycle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I peeked inside the uCommerce Sitecore DLLs and found the class `DataProviderReinitializeTask<T>` which contained code for clearing the dataprovider cache.

To use in any location you'll need code like this:

```
var context = ObjectFactory.Instance.Resolve<UCommerce.Sitecore.ISitecoreContext>();
var dataProviderMaster = context.DataProviderMaster;
if (dataProviderMaster != null)
    dataProviderMaster.DataChangedPleaseReinitialize();
```

Answer (score 0):

You would also need to clear the NHibernate caches. So, run this code and you should be all set.

// uCommerce NHibernate Cahce
ObjectFactory.Instance.Resolve().ClearCache();

// Clear product data provider cache
var sitecoreContext = ObjectFactory.Instance.Resolve();                            sitecoreContext.DataProviderMaster.DataChangedPleaseReinitialize();